# Hive schematool Could not find or load main class PC"

Tags: hadoop, hive, cygwin, derby

```
NASIM'S PC@DESKTOP-DQS0T2A /cygdrive/c
$ export HADOOP_HOME='/cygdrive/c/Hadoop/hadoop-2.7.6'

NASIM'S PC@DESKTOP-DQS0T2A /cygdrive/c
$ export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin

NASIM'S PC@DESKTOP-DQS0T2A /cygdrive/c
$ export HIVE_HOME='/cygdrive/c/Hadoop/hive'

NASIM'S PC@DESKTOP-DQS0T2A /cygdrive/c
$ export PATH=$PATH:$HIVE_ME/bin

NASIM'S PC@DESKTOP-DQS0T2A /cygdrive/c
$ export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$(hadoop classpath)

NASIM'S PC@DESKTOP-DQS0T2A /cygdrive/c
$ export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_CLASSPATH:$HIVE_HOME/lib/*.jar

NASIM'S PC@DESKTOP-DQS0T2A /cygdrive/c
$ echo $HADOOP_HOME
/cygdrive/c/Hadoop/hadoop-2.7.6

NASIM'S PC@DESKTOP-DQS0T2A /cygdrive/c
$ $HADOOP_HOME/sbin/start-all.cmd
This script is Deprecated. Instead use start-dfs.cmd and start-yarn.cmd
starting yarn daemons

NASIM'S PC@DESKTOP-DQS0T2A /cygdrive/c
$ $HIVE_HOME/bin/schematool -dbType derby -initSchema
Error: Could not find or load main class PC
```

please try to solve my issue

Comment: The username is "NASIM'S PC". The space is causing errors in the script, thinking that "PC" is it's own argument. You'll need to use a different user account (and ideally WSL2 rather than cygwin)